# Installing Datalab/Jupyter on Dataproc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to install Jupyter notebook / Datalab on my Dataproc cluster but with no avail.

I follow this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/dataproc-datalab

**Step by step**:

1. I create a new GS Bucket called `datalab-init-bucket-001` and upload there the `datalab.sh` script from GitHub https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/datalab/datalab.sh
   [image]
2. Then start the Dataproc via `gcloud` command with `--initialization-actions 'gs://datalab-init-bucket-001/datalab.sh'`, the entire command looks like:

   `gcloud dataproc create cluster-test --subnet default --zone "" --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size 10 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 10 --initialization-action-timeout "10h" --initialization-actions 'gs://datalab-init-bucket-001/datalab.sh'`

Here, the first problem arises: 
[image]

Looking at the logs:

> OK >  Downloading script [gs://datalab-init-bucket-001/datalab.sh] to
>   [/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0]
>
> OK >  Running script
>   [/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0]
>   and saving output in [/var/log/dataproc-initialization-script-0.log]
>
> OK >  DIR* completeFile:
>   /user/spark/eventlog/.cc2b1d00-4968-4008-87d7-eac090b09e56 is closed
>   by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1150019196_1
>
> ERROR > AgentRunner startup failed: 
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentException: Initialization
>   action failed to start (error=2, No such file or directory). Failed
>   action 'gs://datalab-init-bucket-001/datalab.sh' (TASK_FAILED)    at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentException$Builder.build(AgentException.java:83)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentException$Builder.buildAndThrow(AgentException.java:79)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.throwInitActionFailureException(BootstrapActionRunner.java:236)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runSingleCustomInitializationScriptWithTimeout(BootstrapActionRunner.java:146)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runCustomInitializationActions(BootstrapActionRunner.java:126)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AbstractAgentRunner.runCustomInitializationActionsIfFirstRun(AbstractAgentRunner.java:150)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterAgentRunner.initialize(MasterAgentRunner.java:165)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AbstractAgentRunner.start(AbstractAgentRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterAgentRunner.start(MasterAgentRunner.java:36)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.lambda$boot$0(AgentMain.java:63)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentStatusReporter.runWith(AgentStatusReporter.java:52)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.boot(AgentMain.java:59)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.main(AgentMain.java:46)
>   **Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program**
>   **"/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0":**
>   **error=2, No such file or directory**    at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.util.NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.startAndWrap(NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.java:33)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.util.NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.startAndWrap(NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.java:27)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.createRunner(BootstrapActionRunner.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runScriptAndPipeOutputToGcs(BootstrapActionRunner.java:301)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runSingleCustomInitializationScriptWithTimeout(BootstrapActionRunner.java:142)
>     ... 9 more  Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0":
>   error=2, No such file or directory        ... 15 more     Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory       at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)      at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)        at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)         at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)      ... 14 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory    at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 14 more
>       undefinedE  AgentRunner startup failed:

3. "Manual" installation on the master node VM fails too:
   [image]

I somehow managed to start Datalab on single-node cluster. But I was not able to start the (py)Spark session there.

I run the latest Dataproc image version (1.2), but for example 1.1 also didn't work. I have free credits account, but I guess this should not pose a problem.

Any idea how to update the `datalab.sh` script to make this work?

Comment: Could you attempt to create a cluster again with `--scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'` flag?

Comment: @tix thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it is still not working

Comment: Thanks for trying. I believe this is a transient failure, I will investigate this a bit further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the reason for failure was **not large enough disk**. I switched from 10 GB to 50 GB disk size on each node and suddenly it works.

Comment: Confirm. Got similar problem with dataproc (without datalab, but still) with "Dataproc Agent Startup Failed" and not enough disk warning. I just added enough storage and it started to work as usual.